# Classnot found exception at logger.error in log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, properties-file

I have migrated my jar code from log4j 1.2.8 to 2.17.0. At one point my code is going into an exception in the catch block which look like below code:

```
catch(Exception e){
     logger.error("Error in loading xyz"+e,e);
         }
```

i have added the below code at the start of my class

```
private static final Logger logger= LogManager.getLogger(abcdef.class)
```

The Error I get is below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
```

This error goes aways when i add log4j 1.2.8. But I want to use only log4j 2.17.0

Below is my log4j2.properties file data:

```
status = error

name = PropertiesConfig

property.basepath= target/logs/test

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = filelogger
appender.rolling.fileName = ${basepath}/application.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${basepath}/application.log-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%l] - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = LogToConsole
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n


rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs= stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref= fileLogger
```

Comment: Log4j 2.x is incompatible with Log4j 1.x, therefore you need to add the [Log4j 1.x bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/index.html) to your runtime classpath.

Comment: I'am getting this error at logger.error() part. It works fine at logger.debug(). I changed everything accordingly so that it work with log4j 2.x. I want to completely migrate it.

Comment: Since you want to modify your code, check the [official migration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#Log4j2API). For a basic usage you just need to replace `org.apache.log4j` with `org.apache.logging.log4j` in your code.

Comment: yes i'am using that already.